# could not check in document 'xxxxxxxx': Error initializing dynamic roles for RPC SysObjFullFetch (0bxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

Tags: documentum, retention, webtop

I am getting the following error when trying to check in  the checked out document.
It was working fine earlier till the retention was not working. Currently its fixed and a retention policy is applied to the document. I already have the write access to the document still I am unable to checkin.

[image: on]

I tried to check it in as a new version, however that also not seems to be working.

Comment: This could be problem with not privileged client. Try finding your soulution in that way -> https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=documentum+privilleged+clients&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks Miki for responding, however when looking for links, little confused me. 
As I could understand, I will have  to add webop to the privileged client, is that so?
And if I add it, will have any impact for all the users, regarding access levels or any other?

Comment: pretty much, yeah. take this with caution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime and understanding the whole retention policy thing, I got to understand the reason for the error.

Retention is meant to keep a document from editing or deletion for certain period of time(depends on configured duration for the retention policy applied on it). So even
someone have write or delete access, the document or the object still can not be deleted or edited.

If it is really needed to edit the document, the only way is to do is by first removing the retention policy from the document(which I dont think can be done easily) so its better to plan in advance.